# Unable to download data using Aspera

Tags: download, ftp, fastq, ncbi, rna-seq

I am trying to download data from the [European Nucleotide Archive (ENA)](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ena) using [Aspera](https://downloads.asperasoft.com/en/downloads/2) CLI however my downloads are getting stalled. I have downloaded several files earlier using the same tool but this is happening since last one month. I usually use the following command:

```
ascp -QT -P33001 -k 1 -i ~/.aspera/connect/etc/asperaweb_id_dsa.openssh era-fasp@fasp.sra.ebi.ac.uk:/vol1/fastq/ERR192/009/ERR1924229/ERR1924229.fastq.gz .
```

From a post on [Beta Science](http://betascience.blogspot.com/2010/02/using-aspera-instead-of-ftp-to-download.html), I learnt that this might be due to not limiting the download speed and hence tried usng the `-l` argument but was of no help.

```
ascp -QT -l 300m -P33001 -k 1 -i ~/.aspera/connect/etc/asperaweb_id_dsa.openssh era-fasp@fasp.sra.ebi.ac.uk:/vol1/fastq/ERR192/009/ERR1924229/ERR1924229.fastq.gz .
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your command works.

you might be overdriving your local network ?

how much bandwidth do you have ?

here "-l 300m" sets a target rate to 300 Mbps, if you have less than 30, this can cause such problems.

try to reduce the target rate to what you actually have.
(using wired ? Wifi ?)

Comment: I am on wired connection. Is there a way to check my bandwidth limit or do I need to contact network admin? I suspect that might be the case.